# Best practice to share Tomcat configuration for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tomcat, configuration

We have to deal with a huge amount of different projects with different Tomcat versions and configurations.

What is your best practice to share such config with the team?

So far it was documented in Wiki but it is sometimes incomplete/obsolete/even confising.

Someone suggested using embedded Tomcat through Maven. This could work, but I've heard the plugin is not actively developed anymore.

Another option would be to simply commit the server configuration folders. With the paths it could be tricky. To solve this we would need properties files so this is also a partial solution (not to mention I'm unsure if the run config settings such as VM arguments are stored there).

Or we should simply stick with Wiki pages? :)

Should you have any non-conventional approaches, please leave it in comments, I'll read it for sure.

It would also be a nice addition if we coild share the config with colleagues who are working with IntelliJ.

Comment: What do you need to configure in Tomcat?

Comment: Just the usual thing: catalina.properties, server/context/tomcat-users/web.xml, run config (incl. classpath, VM arguments, ...).

Comment: What is your normal way of working?  Download Tomcat, unzip it, configure it manually, tell connector it exists?

Comment: How about creating a separate git project for configuration? Keeping the separate one for each version and use those one post unzipping of tomcat version.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Yep. The issue is when there is a new property for instance, docs get outdated too soon. I thought keeping it together in a specific repo would be the best, still, I don't know how practical it is (because of conflicting absolute paths for instance).

Comment: @rlegendi Script it!  You are now at the point where it hurts enough to learn to automate it.

Comment: Yeah, well, I prefer avoiding custom solutions :) Thought the problem is generic enough to have some tools or approaches. But well, if that's the only option left, we'll experiment with something.